# Authentication using python Kubernetes api in GCP is not working

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I would like to be able to access  GKE (kubernetes) cluster in GCP from python kubernetes client.
I cant authenticate and connect to my cluster and i dont find the reason.
Here is what i tried so far.

```
from google.auth import compute_engine
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client


def test_gke(request):
    project_id = "myproject"
    zone = "myzone"
    cluster_id = "mycluster"

    credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()

    cluster_manager_client = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
    cluster = cluster_manager_client.get_cluster(name=f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{zone}/clusters/{cluster_id}')

    configuration = client.Configuration()
    configuration.host = f"https://{cluster.endpoint}:443"
    configuration.verify_ssl = False
    configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.token}
    client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    pods = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in pods.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Comment: OK, this isn't obvious IMO but you're close. I've done this in Golang but not Python. Your code is correct to `get_cluster` using `ClusterManagerClient`. Where (I think) you're going wrong is in creating the Kubernetes client config. In the Go client, it is necessary to create a Kubernetes `Config` resource type including the `Cluster` (host and cert), and `User` (defining an AuthProvider for GCP). Then (!) you should be able to make `CoreV1Api` method calls using your GCP credentials.

Comment: As i can see now , the credentials that i get from compute_engine.Credentials() is null . I just start to learn this API so i don't know if i have to configure something in my cluster or i am doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: Yes, the auth is wrong. You should `credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()`. This will get credentials from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` when running locally or from the service (metadata) when running on GCP.

Comment: But, more importantly, I think you need to create a Kubernetes Config object (cluster, user etc.) for GKE that uses those credentials. It would be great if someone else has done this from Python because the SDK is a little different (gnarly) than the Go SDK. I'm having a quick look but I don't have a GKE cluster running currently

Comment: I am not sure if i did the config correct , i follow this :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/

But i keep geting the same error :

kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I'd like to get the configuration working</strike> I have it work where, the code is running off cluster and it produces the `kubectl` config file for itself. (see update at end)

##### Original

The first solution assumes (!) you've the cluster configured in your local (`~/.kube/config` and probably adjusted by `KUBE_CONFIG`) config.

```py
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client,config

config.load_kube_config()
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

resp = api_instance.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
for i in resp.items:
    print(f"{i.status.pod_ip}\t{i.metadata.namespace}\t{i.metadata.name}")
```

> **NOTE**
>
> 1. Assumes you've run `gcloud containers clusters get-credentials` to set the `~/.kube/config` file for the current cluster (and has a `current-context` set.
> 2. Uses your user credentials in the `~/.kube/config` file so no additional credentials are needed.

##### Update

Okay, I have it working. Here's the code that will generate a `kubectl` config and connect to the cluster. This code uses [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python) to provide a Service Account key to the code (usually `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json`)

```py
import os
import google.auth
import base64

from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client,config
from ruamel import yaml

PROJECT = os.getenv("PROJECT")
ZONE = os.getenv("ZONE")
CLUSTER = os.getenv("CLUSTER")

# Get Application Default Credentials
# `project_id` is the Service Account's
# This may differ to the cluster's `PROJECT`
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()

# Get the cluster config from GCP
cluster_manager_client = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)

name=f"projects/{PROJECT}/locations/{ZONE}/clusters/{CLUSTER}"
cluster = cluster_manager_client.get_cluster(name=name)

SERVER = cluster.endpoint
CERT = cluster.master_auth.cluster_ca_certificate

configuration = client.Configuration()

# Create's a `kubectl` config
NAME="freddie" # arbitrary
CONFIG=f"""
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: {NAME}
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: {CERT}
    server: https://{SERVER}
contexts:
- name: {NAME}
  context:
    cluster: {NAME}
    user: {NAME}
current-context: {NAME}
users:
- name: {NAME}
  user:
    auth-provider:
      name: gcp
      config:
        scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
"""

# The Python SDK doesn't directly support providing a dict
# See: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/870
kubeconfig = yaml.safe_load(CONFIG)

loader = config.kube_config.KubeConfigLoader(kubeconfig)
loader.load_and_set(configuration)

api_client= client.ApiClient(configuration)
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)

# Enumerate e.g. Pods
resp = api_instance.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
for i in resp.items:
     print(f"{i.status.pod_ip}\t{i.metadata.namespace}\t{i.metadata.name}")
```

Comment: Great! It's a good question and intrigued me 